extend morphism $\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{P}^1$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$
I am trying to extend an arbitrary morphism $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ following the solution for the Exercise 3.a)
https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2024/fs/401-3146-12L/ex/Solution4.pdf
Question. After the first bullet, the author claims that if the order of $h$ is less than or equal to $m$, the regular function $f$ does not have a pole at $0$. I do not see his point: since $f|_{U_1}\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}(D(g))\cong k[x]_g$, we have $f|_{U_1}=\frac{h}{g^m}$ for some $h\in k[x]$. If $h$ is of some nice forms, e.g. $h=x$, then we have $f|_{U_1}=\frac{x}{g}=\frac{1}{(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_N)}$, which has no pole at $0$. However, we cannot always have such nice $h$. How are we going to "clear" the demominator as the author did?
Any help or comment is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

The author doesn't talk about the order of $h$ in general but the order of $h$ at zero specifically. Does this help?

There's also this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649483/extending-a-morphism-mathbba1-0-to-mathbbp1-to-mathbba1?rq=1

@Dog_69 that first comment of yours looks like an answer to me - please consider recording it as such below. (I agree the link is related, but I'd be unsure about closing it as a duplicate without further discussion.)
